# Why DetourFindFunction() fails to find the address of a function?

Tags: c, winapi, detours

Microsoft's Detour [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/wiki/FAQ) documentation indirectly says that statically linked function cannot be detoured under question **Why don't I see any calls to my detour of malloc?**

But I am able to detour my own statically linked library functions by finding the address using `DetourFindFunction()`.  I believe it uses debug symbols to find it. I have tested enough and I didn't see any abnormal behaviour with this approach? What could be the reason behind Microsoft making such statements in FAQ?

Also if the **inline function expansion** is enabled under visual studio project configuration, `DetourFindFunction()` fails to find the address. Why does it fail and are there any other ways to find the address?

Answer (score 0):

I think what he means is that when you call a function (in static library A) in process B, then you detour the function in process B, it will be failed but not detour the function in static library A directly.

The inline function is executed directly by the compiler by moving the code to the calling place, without the overhead of calling it. The Inline function does not jump to an address to execute.